# split time between start time and end time with one hour interval in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have start time and end  time with time stamp format. Now i want to know how to split time between two things with 60  minutes interval.

I have booking table. so now split the available slots with one hour interval for each date

I have `started ,`ended`slots for booking. For example started is`2014-05-02 18:00:00`and ended is`2014-05-02 22:00:00`. Now I want like this:

```
START TIME
-------------------
2014-05-02 18:00:00
2014-05-02 19:00:00
2014-05-02 20:00:00
2014-05-02 21:00:00
```

Comment: What are you tried so far?

Comment: can you give an example of what you have and how you want it ?

Comment: I have started,ended slots for booking.For example started is '2014-05-02 18:00:00' and ended is '2014-05-02 22:00:00'
now i want like this  
START TIME --
2014-05-02 18:00:00   --
2014-05-02 19:00:00   -- 
2014-05-02 20:00:00   --
2014-05-02 21:00:00

Comment: Are the start and end times connected somehow? Some index to join on?

Comment: Please put some sample data or a fiddle in your question

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
SELECT `START_TIME`
FROM TABLE
WHERE `START_TIME` BETWEEN "2014-05-02 18:00:00" AND "2014-05-02 22:00:00"
```